# Hdmi resolution problem

Tags: resolution, hdmi, external-monitor

I connected my laptop to the tv with a hdmi cable but the 1920x1080 resolution gives me problems. If I set any other resolution is all great because I can set in the settings of the TV the option "dot per dot". But when I change the resolution to 1920x1080 I can not do it. Someone is able to tell me the reason?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: this may be a stupid question, but are you certain your TV supports 1920x1080?

Comment: Yes the tv is a Sharp that supports this resolution.

Comment: I don't know if can be useful but my graphic card is an Intel gma 4500 with driver Intel® Ironlake Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2